# how to make input work in python

Tags: python, split

I want to input a vector in the form "`(x,y,z)`"

```
    s=raw_input("Enter vector (x,y,z): ")
    x,y,z= s.split()
    self.x= float(x)
    self.y= float(y)
    self.z= float(z)
```

What is missing in the code? Shouldn't split do the job?

I tried `s.split("(",",",")")` also, but with no success.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` for such input:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "(1,100,200)"
>>> x, y, z =  ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
```

Using string functions you need to strip `()` first and then split on `,`:

```
>>> x, y, z = s.strip('()').split(',')
>>> x, y, z
('1', '100', '200')
```

Help on `str.split`:

```
S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings
```

> Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the
>       delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
>       splits are done. If **`sep` is not specified or is None**, any
>       **whitespace** string is a separator and empty strings are removed
>       from the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are inputting like this:

```
Enter vector (x,y,z):
> 2,3,4
```

You'd want to do

```
x, y, z = s.split(",")
```

If you're inputting the numbers seperated by comma and space, do this:

```
x, y, z = s.split(", ")
```

`str.split` splits the string into substrings, split on each occurence of the argument supplied (which defaults to " ").

Answer (score 1):

An alternative: capture what you want rather than splitting-away what you don't.

```
import re
s = '(44.2, 19, 12.73)'
floats_rgx = re.compile(r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?')
x, y, z = map(float, floats_rgx.findall(s))
```

That approach has the advantage (or disadvantage, depending on your goals) of allowing more open-ended input formats. If you want something more strict, you could write a complete regular expression to validate the precise input format.

Comment: Might want to also add `-?` to the start of the pattern to handle negative numbers.